# How to remove all ampersands in a string except for specific tokens

Tags: python, regex, string

I need to remove every ampersand in a string except tokens like 'd&g' or 'black&jones'.
For this purpose it must be done using regex. I used this pattern `r'[a-zA-Z]&[a-zA-Z]'` but not working.
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: Why doesn't your solution work? Can you [edit] your question to show the specific problem you have and why your solution does not cover that case?

Comment: description has been edited

Comment: if you create the string you can put a differentiator to identify what is a token and what is a garbage "&", otherwise you can't replace the "&" if you don't have located where a token starts.

Comment: no this is part of a normalizer which used regex. @JahirUnzueta

Comment: What "but not working" means? Also, how "d&g" differs from other ampersands in your text? Is there some kind of rule? If yes, describe it.

Comment: How about `re.sub(r'([a-z]&[a-z])|&','$1',mytext,0,re.I)` ?

Comment: unfortunatly not. this wil will convert `&mostafa & and h&h and& mostafa&mostafa test& a&a` to `mostafa   and   and  mostaf ostafa test` @ChrisMaurer

Comment: And what should it convert to?

Answer (score 1):

Here is answer assuming you want to replace any ampersand except those that are surrounded by English letters.

```py
import re

test_str = "d&g &this &mostafa & and h&m and& mostafa&mostafa &this this& d&g"

print(re.sub(r"&(?![a-zA-Z])|(?<![a-zA-Z])&", "", test_str))
# d&g this mostafa  and h&m and mostafa&mostafa this this d&g
```

Here `&(?![a-zA-Z])|(?<![a-zA-Z])&` matches ampersands that are either not preceded by English letter, or not followed by one: `(?!...)` - negative lookahead, `(?<!...)` - negative lookbehind.

If you want expand list of symbols allowed around ampersands - add those symbols in both symbol classes. For example, if you want to allow digits around use `[a-zA-Z0-9]`.

Answer (score 0):

found suitable regex pattern. Here is completed python code:

```
import re

text = "d&g &this &mostafa & and h&m and& mostafa&mostafa &this this& d&g"

pattern = r"^&|&$|[^a-z]+&|&[^a-z]+"

cleaned_text = re.sub(pattern, " ", text)

print(cleaned_text)
```

Comment: This solution will replace non-letter symbols near `&` with space. For example `Example. &New example` -> `Example New example`